# inserting added column values in another column

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am having one table named student having the following column names and data's

```
NAME   MARK2      MARK3      mark1      total  
surya  85         95         123        
priya   75         95         25         
vishnu   88         75        27
```

is there any way to add column mark1 and mark2 and mark3 and insert that added values in total can you guys suggest me about this.iam using sqlplus database

Comment: yes you can update your table, and set total = mark1+2+3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it this way

```
UPDATE student
   SET total = mark1 + mark2 + mark3;
```

Better yet just create a view

```
CREATE VIEW vw_student AS
SELECT name, mark3, mark2, mark1, mark3 + mark2 + mark1 total
  FROM student;
```

and use it instead

```
SELECT * FROM vw_student;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54c9e4/1)** demo for both approaches

---

**UPDATE:** Based on your comments you can create a trigger (actually two one for `INSERT` and the second for `UPDATE`) to populate `total` column automatically

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_bi_student
BEFORE INSERT ON student
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.total = NEW.mark1 + NEW.mark2 + NEW.mark3;

CREATE TRIGGER tg_bu_student
BEFORE UPDATE ON student
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.total = NEW.mark1 + NEW.mark2 + NEW.mark3;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/845a3/1)** for a trigger approach

---

**2ND UPDATE** Since you actually using Oracle you can just define `total` as a computed column

```
CREATE TABLE student
(
  NAME  VARCHAR2(32), 
  MARK2 NUMBER, 
  MARK3 NUMBER, 
  mark1 NUMBER, 
  total NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (mark1 + mark2 + mark3)
);
```

You can change your table's schema this way

```
ALTER TABLE student DROP COLUMN total;
ALTER TABLE student ADD total NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (mark1 + mark2 + mark3);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/70de0/1)** demo

Comment: that will be work on existing data's i need to add three column values to be added automatically when ever new rows been added total must be add by itself

Comment: Your question is marked with `mysql` tag which is for MySQL Server. But you show the error from Oracle database which is completely different product!

Comment: For Oracle you can just combine both triggers into one `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger. But using trigger should be your last option, why can't you just insert `mark1, mark2, mark3, mark1+mark2+mark3`?

Comment: @peterm are you sure you want to use `int` in your 2nd update and not `number`?

Comment: @peterm as far as I know Oracle casts `int` to `number` internally and `int` is just there for compatibility. Ofc the values are integer values but as said beforehand, int is not an official Oracle datatype.

Comment: @Armunin Thanks for the input. You're right int is an alias for number. **But it works just fine and doesn't change a bit in the light of the question asked**. Anyway I updated the answer for such vigilant persons as you :)

Comment: @peterm I know that it was working, just wanted to make sure you were well aware of that beatuy mark in your answer ;)