# Can I insert data in column right after reading another column?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

current state
table name: mytable

```
before        after
I am a boy.   
I am a girl.
```

expected state
table name: mytable
before        after

```
I am a boy.   I/Pronoun+am/verb+a/adjective+boy/noun+./mark.
I am a girl.  I/Pronoun+am/verb+a/adjective+girl/noun+./mark
```

to get data which will be inserted in 'after' column,
i have to use function outside sql query,
like analysis("I am a boy") which returns "I/Pronoun+am/verb+a/adjective+boy/noun+./mark".

I just got how to use conn.cursor() on conn=sqlite3.connect('database.db')
or
method like this link:
[inserting added column values in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20513775/inserting-added-column-values-in-another-column)

but i want to read a column -> insert it as parameter on python function -> insert it into adjacent column.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This requires some NLP/machine learning, and the SQL tag may not even be appropriate.

Comment: I have tool which can analyze it(I mean, I have function "analysis("I am a boy")".)

Comment: I just want to know how to get data -> use function -> insert it to adjacent column

Comment: @woojin The docs don’t cover that, nor do any guides/tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

you need UDF(User Define Function) of SQLite

1. first, you make(write/define) your own function itself
2. register(declare) it, just like;

   https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html
3. and finally, use(call) it in your Column adding query.

Could be **VERY** hard job to do.

Good Luck To You (포스가 함께 하시기를...)